# TwitteR - Retriving tweets

Tags: r, twitter

I'm trying to use TwitteR in R.... I've got this error and I don't know how to go on.

Can someone give me any suggestion?

Thanks a lot.

[image]

Comment: Your code should be `geocode='44.50359,11.34078,30mi'` with no spaces.  I believe this is the cause of your problem.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work :(